# Adding margin, isn't working the way I want in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make 2 columns with space between but when I try to add **margin-right** the column goes down, can somebody help me

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="boxi col-6">
        a
    </div>
    <div class="boxi col-6">
        a
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure, but did u tried do it like that? If u adding margin to 2xcol-6 there is no more space to keep it in one row since grid have 12 cols. Also u can do it your way but add padding maybe instead of margin?

```
   <div class=row>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="boxi">
            a
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check whether added a `bootstrap` cdn to your html file 
Add bootstrap `container` class

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          aaaaaaa
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        aaaaaa
       </div> 
    </div>
 </div>
```

try with adding negative values to `margin-right` or try with `margin-left` or `padding left or right property`

Comment: I tried even this one but didnt work, thanks a lot for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to shift other column down then you probably need to maintain inline column properties within `DIVs`.

*Try:*

```
padding: 0 15px 0 0;
```

*OR:*

```
padding-right: 15px;
```